# Programatically setting constraints is leading to views overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to write some code to display two views within a constraint layout. I have used the following code so that the first view should appear on the left of the screen, and the second on the right.

```
 ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
       set.clone(cl);


       set.connect(tv.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
       set.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);

       set.applyTo(cl);
```

However when I run my app the two views just appear in the centre overlapping each other.

The code for my two views is:

```
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new 
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
       );

       params3.setMargins(8,8,8,8);


       ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new 
       ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
       );


       params4.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
       );



       TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
       tv.setText(LeagueName);
       tv.setTextSize(18);
       tv.setLayoutParams(params3);

       ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
       img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.basketball);
       img.setLayoutParams(params4);

 cl.addView(tv);
 cl.addView(img);


       card.addView(cl);
       mLayout.addView(card);
```

I'm new to android so I've almost certainly missed something fundamental.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that the parent's parent has finished it's measuring pass?

Comment: @Shark Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: hello @user1627774, can you post the code for your tv & img please ? Are you creating them dynamically ?

Comment: Hi @mdb_5203 I have added the code to my original post. Yes they are generated within a for loop corresponding to stored data.

Comment: @user1627774, try using chains. check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains.

Comment: @mdb_5203 Thanks! It turned out it was an issue with the view Ids being the same.

Answer (score 2):

So after a lot of playing around I've discovered that getId() returns the same default value for each element and so each time I added a new constraint I was applying it to every view. The way around this is to use setId() every time you create a new view in order to ensure they remain unique.